# I can't open my Pokemon Go account

Tags: pokemon-go, technical-issues

I can't open the Pokemon Go account of my trainer club. Another account (Google account) is working, but not the trainer club one. It says "Unable to authenticate, please try again". What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try logging in here and see if it gives you any errors: https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/caslogin

Comment: I meant for this to be a comment. Oh well. This should help you narrow down the problem though.

Comment: You need 50 rep to comment. This is valid as an answer though, so you should be fine.